# LUB for Function2 and Function3 trait

Tags: scala

I have a function that has type

```
(String, String) => String
```

And another function that has type

```
(String, String, String) => String
```

Is there a way to cleanly create a common trait/superclass so that I can pass a list of them?

Edit:
I am passing more information on this because experts are curious as to my I want to add the two above types in a list. I am trying to add them ((String, String) => String and (String, String, String) => String) to a list because i am creating a test suite that takes a list of Tables and run a method that checks a condition (condition is the method).

So I am trying to create a class like this

```
type DatabaseName = String
type TableName = String
type ColName = String
type Output = String

class TestFn(functionName : String, listOfTables : List[String], functionToRun : (DatabaseName, TableName) => Output)
```

I take the output and store it as a dataframe. I want this to be extendable. Another developer came to me and showed me a test case that contains this signature

```
(DatabaseName, TableName, ColName) => String
```

So I want to be able to create a superclass/trait so that it can take any function ((String, String) => String or (String, String, String) => String) and run that function on his list of tables

Comment: I doubt it, unless you want `Any`, since you'll have to cast it later anyway. What do you need this for? There may be a workaround.

Comment: How would you call such a function?

Comment: Consider calling `.tupled` on these functions first, so you can do `[T <: Product](f: T => String)`. I would just recommend a `List[String]`, however. I don't see much point in using a homogenous tuple.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, I have provided more information, please check

Comment: If you want to run the functions on List[String], adapt them to match that signature, e.g. like: `(seq: List[String]) => f(seq(0), seq(1), seq(2))`.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question, assuming you would be able to have both functions in a list, how would you call them? If you pass only two arguments but the list was of three then you would be missing one _unless you have a defaullt_, if you pass three and the function was one of two it would ignore one, or would you want to check if it is a function of two or of three to decide how to call it? Or maybe each function should also have its parameters already defined and you only want to delay its execution? Or... - so, again, how would you can such a function?

Comment: You could perhaps use an `Either[(String, String) => String, (String, String, String) => String]`, but as @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez said, you should also add how you're using the functions to this question.

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response, but yes @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you are correct in asking that question. When I was implementing, I realised that I had to then convert the (String, String) => String to (String, String, String) => String for adding it into a loop

Comment: @jwvh, yes you did that too. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is rather thin and presents a few questions:

1. Do you actually have methods or real functions?
2. Can you modify the function code or should they remain unaltered?
3. Why do you want to wrap them in a `List`? What purpose do you hope to achieve? (This looks like a classic [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).)
4. How do you imagine invoking the functions when extracted from the `List`?

Taking your question as presented, lets start with a couple of type aliases, to make the code easier to read, and a simple (somewhat silly) implementation of each.

```
type Str2Func = (String,String) => String
type Str3Func = (String,String,String) => String

val s2f:Str2Func = (x,y) => x.toUpperCase + y.toLowerCase
val s3f:Str3Func = (x,y,z) => z + y + x
```

After putting these in a `List` we can see the current LUB (Least Upper Bound) for these types.

```
List(s2f, s3f)  //List[Object]
```

Not terribly useful, but then, it's hard to imagine a LUB that covers both types and can execute (invoke) both types.

One possible solution would be to promote every `Str2Func` to an `Str3Func` that simply ignores one of its arguments.

This transformation can be done automatically but implicit conversions can be dangerous, and are [sometimes discouraged](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/can-we-wean-scala-off-implicit-conversions/4388), so we'll make the conversion explicit but unobtrusive.

```
implicit class SF2to3(f2:Str2Func) {
  def to3: Str3Func = (a:String, b:String, _:String) => f2(a,b)
}

val s3fs:List[Str3Func] = List(s2f.to3, s3f)
```

And each element can be invoked independently.

```
s3fs.map(_("Aa","Bb","Cc"))
//res0: List[String] = List(AAbb, CcBbAa)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added more information, please check.